# Changing messy Tumblr URL

Tags: url, blog, tumblr

On Tumblr we keep getting really messy URLs generated for our blog posts. Is there any way that this can be changed?

For instance, in the example bellow, the blogs title is ‘Playing with scale and proportion’ so I’d like the URL to read

> /post/playing-with-scale-and-proportion

without all the numbers in-between.

[image]

Comment: If that is a "messy" URL, then StackExchange's URLs are "messy."

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do that on Tumblr.

All those "messy numbers" is the Tumblr's Globally Unique Post ID. The part that follows (the "slug") has no identifying purpose on Tumblr -- All that matters is the Post ID.

For example, these are all equivalent URLs:

- my-blog.tumblr.com/post/123456789/my-post-slug-that-tumblr-generated
- my-blog.tumblr.com/post/123456789
- my-blog.tumblr.com/123456789

Comment: does it have any effect on seo ? Are Urls similar to title tags ie. the ealier on the keyword is mensioed the more weight it has

Comment: I'm not sure of the effect on SEO, sorry.  As to the URL "slug" -- Tumblr's "slug generator" seems to just take the first few words from the Title of the post (if it exists), or else from the Caption of the post.  However, you have the option of specifying your own "slug" on the Tumblr Post Creating screen.  Look right under the "tags" section, you can enter your own post slug.